# What user agent is this?

Tags: http, user-agent

I receive this string I want to identify the user agent and the browser he uses it listed mozilla i see apple string and KHTML,Gecko Safarii It's hard to identify what browser really he uses.

Please help me identify the user agent,OS or device

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Safari version 5.1.1 (the latest version) running on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 (the latest version).

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.useragentstring.com

```
Safari 5.1.1

- Mozilla         Mozilla ProductSlice. Claims to be a Mozilla based user agent, 
                  which is only true for Gecko browsers like Firefox and 
                  Netscape. For all other user agents it means 
                  'Mozilla-compatible'. In modern browsers, this is only used 
                  for historical reasons. It has no real meaning anymore
- 5.0             Mozilla version
- Macintosh       Platform
- Intel Mac OS X  Operating System: OS X Version 10_7_2 : running on a 
  10_7_2          Intel CPU
- AppleWebKit     The Web Kit provides a set of core classes to display web 
                  content in windows
- 534.51.22       Web Kit build
- KHTML           Open Source HTML layout engine developed by the KDE project
- like Gecko      like Gecko...
- Version         Safari Version
- 5.1.1           Version
- Safari          Name :Safari
- 534.51.22       Safari build number
```

You may also want to look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.15